# Problem with mouseout function when showing and hiding a div

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation item which, when clicked, shows a hidden div. I'm having trouble getting the div to hide when you mouseout of the div. I would like it to hide when the user's mouse leaves the bounds of the div. Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li#locations a').click( 
        function(){ 
            $('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown(); 
        }
    ); 
    $('#locationsSuperNav').mouseout( 
        function(){ 
            $('#locationsSuperNav').slideUp(); 
        }
    );
});
```

There are links and images inside the #locationsSuperNav div. When the cursor hovers over those elements, the div will hide. Is there any way to prevent this??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use the [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event handler rather than mouseout.

```
$('#locationsSuperNav').mouseleave( 
    function(){ 
        $('#locationsSuperNav').slideUp(); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) use [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) here, like this:

```
$('#locationsSuperNav').mouseleave(function(){ 
  $(this).slideUp(); 
});
```

Unlike [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) which fires *even when entering children*, [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) won't.  From the docs:

> The `mouseleave` event differs from `mouseout` in the way it handles event bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the **Inner** element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseleave` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the **Outer** element, but not the **Inner** element.

You can also use `this` inside a handler to refer to the element in question, no need to run the selector again, like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mouseleave instead of mouseout, I didn't checked, but it may work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li#locations a').click( 
    function(){ 
        $('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown(); 
    }
); 
$('#locationsSuperNav').mouseleave( 
    function(){ 
        $('#locationsSuperNav').slideUp(); 
    }
);});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the mouseout event is fired whenever the cursor leaves the targeted element -- including when it moves inside of a child element.  jQuery can help you handle this by using the .hover() function instead: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

This will allow you to bind an event to whenever the mouse come into your element or it's child elements, and when it leaves the encompassing area of your element, with children being included as part of that area.  So you might do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('li#locations a').click( 
        function(){ 
            $('#locationsSuperNav').slideDown(); 
        }
    ); 
    $('#locationsSuperNav').hover(function() {},  
        function(){ 
            $('#locationsSuperNav').slideUp(); 
        }
    );
});
```

This will do nothing when you hover into the #locationsSuperNav element, and perform your slideUp() when you hover out of it.

Should you desire to, you can also fill in some functionality for the hover in event.

Comment: There's no need for `.hover()` here, it's a shortcut for `.mouseeneter(func1).mouseleave(func2)`, if you're only after one might as well use it directly instead of attaching an extra handler :)